# Автоматическое скачивание приложения после оплаты

Tags: java, android, mobile, мобильная-разработка, платежи

Есть мобильное приложение версия "LITE", и есть его версия "FULL" (платная).

Как реализовать покупку прямо в LITE-приложении так, чтобы по нажатию на кнопку открывалась форма Billing, и после оплаты скачивалась FULL-версия?

Мануалы гуглил — всё какие-то отдельные строки: не могу составить полной картины. 
Распишите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Вам скопировать мануал официальный или вы всё же скажете на каком именно моменте проблема возникает?

Comment: Если у вас есть работающий пример? Буду очень благодарен.

Comment: Есть работающий для подписок. Но он в закрытом проекте и я не имею права его в открытый доступ выкладывать. Придётся вам пояснить что конкретно из офиц. мануала вам не понятно.

Answer (score 1):

А не подойдет вам немного измененный вариант?

1. Публикуете FULL приложение за соответствующую цену (при этом бонус - его смогут купить и сразу напрямую).
2. В LITE приложении по кнопке вызываете процедуру установки FULL версии:

   ```
   try {
       startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + PACKAGE_NAME)));
   } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException e) {
       startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + PACKAGE_NAME)));
   }
   ```

Comment: Именно такой способ и используется сейчас. 
Хочу добавить нормальную функцию